# Powershell code error

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

The below is my code.

I want to get the number of rows present in some of the text files separately.

`$myobject =Get-ChildItem C:\Powershell\Deepak -Recurse|select name,fullname|Where-Object name -in txt1.txt,txt2.txt,txt5.txt,txt9.txt|Select fullname -ExpandProperty fullname
Get-Content -path $myobject`

But i am getting the combined out put of all files. I need output in below format

FileName Count

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code you're counting the lines... Script below will count lines "on the fly" in pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Powershell\Deepak -Recurse | where-object name -in txt1.txt,txt2.txt,txt5.txt,txt9.txt | select name, @{name="rc"; expression={(get-content $_.FullName | measure-object).Count}}
```

Comment: thank you...'$myobject =Get-ChildItem C:\Powershell\Deepak -Recurse|select name,fullname|Where-Object name -in txt1.txt,txt2.txt,txt5.txt,txt9.txt|Select fullname -ExpandProperty fullname
(Get-Content -path $myobject).count' my code was like this. But your code worked for me thanks